# MySql joining rows distinctly based on column criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table 1 that i would like to join with another table 2, table 2 has more than one row with different activities, so what i want to do is to do away with duplication on joining then if the column of a tale 2 has a both read and write activities. If the row has both, only show the row with write activity and the date only and if the other rows has no other activities other than read, show null for the date column, rows should be distinct

Table 1

```
id  |   labref
------------------
1   |  123
2   |  456
3   |  789
4   |  1011
5   |  1213
------------------
```

Table 2

```
id | labref | Activity | date
-------------------------------
1  |   123  |  read    | 29
2  |   123  |  Write   | 30
3  |   456  |  Write   | 31
4  |   789  |  read    | 04
5  |   1213 |  read    | 29
6  |   1011 |  read    | 04
7  |   1011 |  Write   | 05
-------------------------------
```

Result Table

```
id | labref | Activity | date
-------------------------------
1  |   123  |  Write   | 30
2  |   456  |  Write   | 31
3  |   789  |  read    | NULL
4  |   1213 |  read    | NULL
5  |   1011|  Write    | 05
-------------------------------
```

Any Suggestions on how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t2.id,t2.labref,
case when t2.activity in ('read','write') Then t2.activity ='write'
     when t2.activity ='read' then t2.date =null
end as activity,
max(t2.date)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
group by t2.labref
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT
    t1.labref,
    IFNULL(t2bis.Activity, t2.Activity),
    t2bis.Date
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.labref = t1.labref
                        AND t2.Activity = 'read'
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2bis ON t2bis.labref = t1.labref
                           AND t2bis.Activity = 'write'
```

---

**Explanations**

- You `LEFT JOIN` a copy of table2 with only the read values
- You `LEFT JOIN` another copy of table2 with only the write values

For the activity: You display the labref for all rows, if there is no write, you display the read (if there is no read, then null will be displayed)

For the date: The date will only be displayed if there is a write activity, so you display the date column of your write table2 copy.

`IFNULL()` displays the first expression if it's not `NULL`, otherwise, it displays the second one.

Comment: Huh, my answer was invalidated, was something wrong? Could I get feedback on that?